# Build pipeline's default branch. What does it mean?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

In the Release workflow in Azure DevOps Services, while setting up Continuous Deployment trigger, there is this option which

> 'The build pipeline's default branch'

. I don't understand what it means and how can I view the default branches for different pipelines in my project. Any reference to documentation on this aspect will also help

This appears in a couple of other places also in the Pipelines, but I can't remember it now.

Thanks,

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/customize-pipeline?view=azure-devops#customize-ci-triggers) describes the default branch is usually the master branch, but you can configure your default branch in your build pipeline settings.

You can view The build pipeline's default branch in your build pipeline settings. Please check below screenshots

> 1.For classic UI build pipeline.

**Tasks > Get sources > Default branch for manual and scheduled builds**

[image]

> 2. For Yaml build pipeline

**Click 3 dots on the top right corner > Triggers > Yaml > Get Sources > Default branch for manual and scheduled builds**

[image]

[image]

Below is the description for **The build pipeline's default branch** build filter in release pipeline. Hope it is helpful for your understanding. Please check this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/release/triggers?view=azure-devops#release-triggers) for more information.

> Alternatively, you can specify a filter to use the default branch specified in the build pipeline. This is useful when, for example, the default build branch changes in every development sprint. It means you don't need to update the trigger filter across all release pipelines for every change - instead you just change the default branch in the build pipeline.

Comment: Thanks a lot. This is useful. As an aside, this seems to be buried so deep in some very non intuitive set of options.