# Azure DevOps yaml pipeline trigger

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

My pipeline trigger in Azure DevOps does not fire.

Enviroment:

- PipelineA (branch dev)
- PipelineB (branch dev)

PipelineB should be fired if PipelineB was running successfully

Here is my current code of PipelineB.yaml

```
trigger: none


resources:        
  pipelines:
  - pipeline: build_pipeline  
    source: PipelineA
    branch: dev
    trigger:
     branches:
     - dev

steps:
- task: Bash@3
  inputs:
    targetType: 'inline'
    script: |
      echo 'Hello world'
```

It worked in the past, but suddenly it stopped

Comment: Hi Wibbico, is there any update for this issue? Does the answer below resolve your question, If yes, you could [Accept it as an Answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/515442) , so it could help other community members who get the same issues and we could archive this thread, thanks. (Feel free to let me know if you're still blocked, I'll try best to help!)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the document of [Pipeline Triggers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/pipeline-triggers?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml), please check this statement:

> However, if the two pipelines use different repositories, then the triggered pipeline will use the latest version of the code from its default branch.

**Cause of your issue:**

The triggered pipeline is `PipelineB` in your scenario, and the `default branch` is always the `master`. Since the pipeline trigger for `dev` branch of `PipelineA` is defined in your `dev` branch instead of the default `master` branch, it's expected behavior that the pipeline trigger won't fire.

**To make the pipeline trigger work:**

1.You can choose to define the pipeline trigger for `dev of PipelineA` in default `master` of `PipelineB`.

2.Or you can change the `Default branch for manual and scheduled builds` of `PipelineB` (Change it from master to dev). You can find detailed steps about how to find this setting from [#2 of this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59745061/10910450).

Both two choices above can resolve your issue and make the pipeline trigger work.

Answer (score 0):

I just created almost identical pipeline

```yaml
trigger: none

resources:        
  pipelines:
  - pipeline: build_pipeline  
    source: kmadof.devops-manual (14)
    branch: master
    trigger:
     branches:
     - master

steps:
- task: Bash@3
  inputs:
    targetType: 'inline'
    script: |
      echo 'Hello world'
```

and all works fine. Are you sure you run PipelineA on `dev` branch?